# Cant load image to FabricJS Canvas

Tags: angular, fabricjs

I have an Angular 5 app that uses a .Net Core api to store and download images.  I can get the images to display using an img tag in the front end but in the typescript code I need to add the image to a FabricJS Canvas.  I have something like this:

```
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(s); // eg: "blob:http://localhost:4200/8a8eda37-81d8-4392-ab26-4e4e10075f98"
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, oImg => {
      oImg.set( {
        left: this.convertor.ToPixels(this.shape.origin.x, this.units),
        top: this.convertor.ToPixels(this.shape.origin.y, this.units),
        // top: 0, //this.shapeElement.top,
        // left: 0, //this.shapeElement.left,
        width: this.shapeElement.width,
        height: this.shapeElement.height
      });
      this.imageElement = oImg;
      // this.canvas.fabric.add(this.imageElement);
      group.add(this.imageElement);
    });
```

You can see I've tried various co-ordinates.  Nothing seems to work.

The group contains 2 other objects - a rectangle and some text.  I want the image to be a background in the rectangle with the text over the top.

The image will only display if I add it to the canvas directly.  I really would prefer to add it to a group with other objects.  It may be that the rectangle is hiding the image, even though it has a transparent fill ?

Any help gratefully accepted :)

Cheers

Comment: to add object to group use `group.addWithUpdate(obj)`

Comment: That explains why my co-ordinates were funcky.  Thanks.  I think it (or something else I did) has also fixed image loading.  Cheers